# Jquery selecting a cell using $('#mytable tbody tr:nth-child() td:nth-child()')

Tags: javascript, jquery, cell

```
for (var i = 0; i <= $('#table-body tr').length - 1; i++) {
    var ingredients = $('#recipiestable tbody tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(1)').text()
    var amount = $('#recipiestable tbody tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(2)').text()
    var unit = $('#recipiestable tbody tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(3)').text()
    $('#resultsbody').append('<tr><td>' + ingredients + '</td><td>' + amount + '</td><td>' + unit + '</td> </tr>')
}
```

How can I select the nth-child using i in the loop? I've tried:

```
$('#recipiestable tbody tr:nth-child('+ i +') td:nth-child(1)')
```

But it just returns errors, does anyone know how to work around this?

Comment: *"But it just returns errors"* What errors? Note that `nth-child` is `1` based, so you should use `(i+1)` instead (or start your loop from `1`). But apart from that, your attempt looks fine.

Comment: What does i return when you console.log it?

Comment: Try eq() https://api.jquery.com/eq/  `$('#recipiestable tbody tr:eq('+ i +') td:eq(1)')`

Comment: It says ` function not defined`

Comment: I still get uncaught ReferenceError: newRow is not defined 

newRow is the name of the function

Comment: Then obviously we are not seeing all the code. May I suggest you do a fiddle on your problem on jsfiddle.net You can start by adding stuff here http://jsfiddle.net/GY5Ef/1/

Comment: I don't see `newRow` anywhere, so obviously it is not defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about a little refactoring to better understand your code?

```
var table_size = $('#table-body tr').length;
var trs = $('#recipiestable tbody tr').slice(table_size);

$.each(trs, function(i, tr) {
  // No need for messy lookups, if you can look inside the context of your current tr
  var ingredients = $('td:nth-child(1)', tr).text(),
      amount      = $('td:nth-child(2)', tr).text(),
      unit        = $('td:nth-child(3)', tr).text();

  $('#resultsbody').append('<tr><td>' + ingredients + '</td><td>' + amount + '</td><td>' + unit + '</td> </tr>');
});
```

docs for [$.each](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)

Comment: oh wait, I thought you're going over the trs of `#table-body` and not `#recipiestable`

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var i = 0; i <= $('#table-body tr').length - 1; i++) {
    var ingredients = $('#recipiestable tbody tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(1)').text();
    var amount = $('#recipiestable tbody tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(2)').text();
    var unit = $('#recipiestable tbody tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(3)').text();
    $('#resultsbody').append('<tr><td>' + ingredients + '</td><td>' + amount + '</td><td>' + unit + '</td> </tr>');
}
```

**Please add the semicolons ;**